# Does arXiv prevent your work from getting scooped, or the opposite?

Tags: publications, arxiv, preprint

On the one hand, it seems like a preprint can discourage dishonest reviewers or editors (who get to see new work before anyone else) from running off with ideas since you have proof of originality with a preprint. On the other hand, a preprint puts the ideas out there to the world at large. What do you think is the safest approach, submitting to journals with or without a preprint?

Comment: Assuming you are dishonest person, I'd advise that the vast majority of what's posted on ArXiv or in journals is simply not worth scooping.  Scooping is not something one really needs to worry about in practice.

Comment: It may allow others to start to build on your work earlier. It depends on you whether that is a good thing or not. Is it a low-hanging fruit that still needs some milking? Or are just afraid of loosing the priority for your current work?

Answer (score 31):

Preprint services prevent scooping.

Every preprint service puts a date stamp on every document that is published there (and in many cases a [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) as well). That's an effectively unmodifiable record of the time when something went live, at which point nobody can republish your result elsewhere with an earlier date stamp with any reputable publisher.

That said, preprints will not prevent competition for the generation of *follow-on* research based on a result, nor will it prevent somebody from claiming independent discovery of the same result. Those, however, are just a normal part of doing business in science.

Comment: ChemRxiv does assign DOIs

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You're right; I'd forgotten that for arXiv the DOI comes from the journal later. bioRxiv assigns the DOI immediately, as do all of the others I've recently interacted with.

Comment: If I submitted a paper to arxiv, and it produced tons of follow-on research that cited my paper, I would be generally quite pleased.

Comment: @puppetsock Typically yes! Some people are much more fearful or greedy, e.g., believing that a particular paper opens up a lot of "low hanging fruit" results that they want to gather themselves as well. I believe that such views are typically short-sighted, but I can see how people come to hold them.